# Changing attr of appended button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a button, that is created by jquery after success of ajax call.
I wanted to change its background-color also by jquery but it doesn't work at all.
What is interesting, I have tried to add exactly the same button outside of the script, in html area and it works fine. How to deal with it?

```
<script>
$(".submitInput1").click(function() {

    event.preventDefault();
    $(".toBanList").html("");

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET"
        url: "/searchFriendsToBlock",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {

        },
        success: function(msg) {
            for (var i = 0; i <= msg.length; i++) {
                $(".banSearchResultList").append("<li class='toBanList'><img class='avatarImage' src='" + msg[i]['avatar'] + "'>" + msg[i]['login'] + "<br>" + msg[i]['first_name'] + " " + msg[i]['last_name'] +
                    "<button class='blockButton2' style='background-color:blue'>Block user</button>\n\
                       <button class='blockButton1' style='background-color:blue'>Block chat</button></li>");
            }
        }

    });

});
</script>


<script>
$(".blockButton1").click(function() {
    $(".blockButton1").css("background-color", "red");
    $(".blockButton1").attr("background-color", "red");

})
</script>
```

Comment: Try appending `<button class='blockButton1' style='background-color:red'>Block chat</button></li>` in for loop. Why to set it using jQuery if you can write it using `inline css` or `class`

Comment: @RayonDabre But i need them to be blue and to change after click

Comment: In that case you are binding events when elements does not exist in DOM. Read about event [delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) or simply bind events after `append` operation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive the problem is that click() only works on elements that exist in the `DOM` when you register the handler. Try using `on()` instead: http://api.jquery.com/on/

In your example:

```
$(".banSearchResultList").on('click','.blockButton1',function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use event delegation, since the button is created dynamically, using the `on` method as follows :

```
$(".banSearchResultList").on("click", ".blockButton1", function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

please use this

```
$("body").on('click', '.blockButton1', function(e) {

              $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(".submitInput1").click(function() {

   event.preventDefault();
   $(".toBanList").html("");

   $.ajax({
      type: "GET"
      url: "/searchFriendsToBlock",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {

      },
      success: function(msg) {
        for (var i = 0; i <= msg.length; i++) {
            $(".banSearchResultList").append("<li class='toBanList'><img class='avatarImage' src='" + msg[i]['avatar'] + "'>" + msg[i]['login'] + "<br>" + msg[i]['first_name'] + " " + msg[i]['last_name'] +
                "<button class='blockButton2' style='background-color:blue'>Block user</button>\n\
                   <button class='blockButton1' style='background-color:blue'>Block chat</button></li>");
        }
       // Adding this line of code. 

        $(".blockButton1").on('click',function() { 
          $(".blockButton1").css("background-color", "red");
        });

       // End
      }

   });
});
</script>
```

You have to add commented block of code in success of ajax call otherwise it will not work. Because the syntax I used it only work if your selector is exist in your DOM.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because it can be difficult for the original poster (or future readers) to understand the logic behind them. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Danniel have you tried my code. It is working as I have select blockButton1 and registering click event on it.

Comment: @Lalit Shingadiya edit question and add commens there, what you did and how it will work.